# javascript - drop down display on the second field based on selection in first field

Tags: javascript, html-select

I have two fields customer category and customer type, 
when I select one element in customer category , I need to display only a set of elements from customer type in the drop down and rest should not appear.
how do write it in javascript. Here is the one I tried but it doesnot yield proper result.

```
var custcategory = document.getElementById("custcatid");
var custtypes = document.getElementById('custtypeid').options;
alert('yes');
var n = custtypes.length;
var allowedtype;

if (custcategory.options[custcategory.selectedIndex].value == "ANALOGUE") {
    alert('ANALOGUE');
    allowedtype = 'CATV,CATV RURAL';
}

else if (custcategory.options[custcategory.selectedIndex].value == "COMMERCIAL") {
    alert('COMMERCIAL');
    allowedtype = ' ,3ST HOTEL,4ST HOTEL,5ST HOTEL';
}

else if (custcategory.options[custcategory.selectedIndex].value == "DAS") {
    alert('DAS');
    allowedtype = ' ,DAS PHASE1,DAS PHASE2,DAS PHASE3,DAS PHASE4';
}

else if (custcategory.options[custcategory.selectedIndex].value == "DTH") {
    alert('DTH');
    allowedtype = ' ,DTH';
}

var idx = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var type = custtypes[i].value;
    var found = allowedtype.search(type);

    if (found <= 0) {
        custtypes[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if (idx == 0) {
        idx = 1;
        document.getElementById('ctl00_uxPgCPH_custtype').selectedIndex = i;
    }

}

alert('Done..!');
```

Comment: Have you tried the approch of having a hidden third `<select>` containing all entries of customer types? Before your `for`-loop you would empty the visible customer type list, then populate it from the hidden one? Also: Your `else if`-part will never run, since `idx` starts as `1` and thus can never be `0`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to filter a second select element based on what is selected in the first select element?

If so I put together the following snippet which might help you out. It can be probably be optimised further but it should help to get you started I feel.

```js
(function () {
  var CLASSES = {
    categories: '.select__category',
    types     : '.select__types'
  },
    map = {
      ANALOGUE: [
        'CATV',
        'CATV RURAL'
      ],
      COMMERCIAL: [
        '3ST HOTEL',
        '4ST HOTEL',
        '5ST HOTEL'
      ],
      DAS: [
        'DAS PHASE 1',
        'DAS PHASE 2',
        'DAS PHASE 3'
      ]
    },
    categorySelect = document.querySelector(CLASSES.categories),
    typeSelect     = document.querySelector(CLASSES.types),
    filterTypes = function(val) {
      // Based on a value filter the types select.
      var opts = typeSelect.options,
        allowedOpts = map[val];
      typeSelect.value = allowedOpts[0];
      for(var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
        if (allowedOpts.indexOf(opts[i].value) === -1) {
          opts[i].hidden = true;
        } else {
          opts[i].hidden = false;
        }     
      }
    };


  filterTypes(categorySelect.value);

  categorySelect.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    filterTypes(this.value);
  });

}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <select id="categories" class="select__category">
    <option value="ANALOGUE">Analogue</option>
    <option value="COMMERCIAL">Commercial</option>
    <option value="DAS">Das</option>
  </select>
  <select id="types" class="select__types">
    <option value="CATV">Catv</option>
    <option value="CATV RURAL">Catv Rural</option>
    <option value="3ST HOTEL">3st Hotel</option>
    <option value="4ST HOTEL">4st Hotel</option>
    <option value="5ST HOTEL">5st Hotel</option>
    <option value="DAS PHASE 1">Das Phase 1</option>
    <option value="DAS PHASE 2">Das Phase 2</option>
    <option value="DAS PHASE 3">Das Phase 3</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

If you run the snippet, you'll see that making changes to the first will update the second select accordingly based on the defined map.

Hope this can help you out!